# SVG Move using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a tspan -

```
<tspan>Some text</tspan>
```

I can get this element in Javascript so

```
parentElement.lastChild -> this is tspan
```

How do I set the x and y to 2 and 4 in JavaScript? So it should be equivalent to

```
 <tspan x="2" y="4">Some text</tspan>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
yourElement.setAttribute("x","2");
yourElement.setAttribute("y","4");
```